# How to set up file copying to FTP server with VS Release Management (TFS on-premises)

Tags: tfs, ftp, release-management

I have an on-premises installation of TFS 2015/VS Release Management (2015).

[image]

For one of the release templates, I need to set up copying of the files from the local network share to FTP server. Among the tasks that are available out-of-the-box I do not see FTP upload:

[image]

Any ideas if and how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own script to do it. You can add it as a custom tool.

However, I'd advise against investing effort in extending the on-prem Release Management solution, as it has been deprecated for 3 years and is no longer receiving updates. Upgrade your TFS to a modern version and migrate to the new Release capabilities built in to the software.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. When you say "upgrade your TFS to a modern version" do you mean VSTS?

Comment: @myroslav Not necessarily. Any recent version of TFS (TFS 2015, 2017, 2018) all support the new release management experience. Newer versions have more features and will be supported for longer, of course.

Comment: it is 2015 version of TFS and VS Release Management that I have installed. Sorry, I should have included that info earlier. I have updated the question.

Comment: @myroslav TFS 2015 Update 2 introduced a totally different release management feature that does not require a separate server and client. You should be using that.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I will try the upgrade. So from your suggestion, it follows that in the TFS 2015 Update 2, there is a built-in task for FTP file uploads then?